# Data modeling : Data without uniqueness

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver

I have a use case where data needs to be dumped into DB, that is not having any uniqueness. Say some random data, that can have repeated values, generated at very high speed.

Now Cassandra has constraint of having partition key per table mandatory.
Even though I can introduce a TimeUUID column, but again problem comes while retrieving. That again can be handled using ALLOW FILTER in Select clause.

I am looking for some better approach. Anyone can suggest some other approach. Only constraint is I can only dump data in Cassandra DB, File system not available.

Comment: How do you plan to retrieve the data? What is the key? Please add data schema, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you just want to store your data without knowing yet how to query it. With Cassandra, you typically need to know how to query it before you design your data model. If you want to retrieve the full data set, you will have poor performance. You might want to consider hdfs instead.

If you really need to store in Cassandra, try to think of a way to store it that makes sense. For example, you could store your data in timebucket. Try to size your bucket to store about 1MB worth of data. If you produce 1MB of data per minute, then a minute bucket is appropriate. You would have a partition key as the minute of the date, then a clustering column as timeUUID, then the rest of your data to store.

Comment: Thanks Christophe Schmitz for sharing your views. I do aggree with you and as I already told, I have no choice to use HDFS or any other file system. SO I have to proceed with known limitation of poor performance. I will rather prefer timeuuid as partition key. As with this I can select a small window of data:                                                                                               DateTimeOffset dateOffset = uuidValue.GetDate();
DateTime dateTime = dateOffset.DateTime;